# Setting boundaries for JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jtextarea

I am new on using Swings

**my requirement is  to align components within the jpanel(panel2)**

I have taken 2 `JPanel`s (`panel1`, `panel2`) and added to the `jframe`

```
panel1.add(panel2);

panel2.setLayout(new flowLayout()); 

panel2.setBounds(80,120,100,100);

getContentPane() .add(Panel1);
```

and I have created a "Create" button that will generate text area dynamically in panel2

now my problem is **if the created textarea is reaching out of `panel2` it has to show an error 
message "You reached the boundaries of the jpanel so the textarea cant be created "**

Thanks in advance

Comment: hard to say something cleaver, there are panel1 and Panel1, where is true, then probably everything is about guessing, for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), short runnable, compilable, just about JFrame and a.m. JPanels

Comment: The question is why? What are you trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to make sure that textarea that are created dynamically will be within the panel2 using flowLayout means I want to give user to create any number of textareas but I have to make sure that it is within the panel2

Comment: I dont want to add the JScrollbar or JScrollpane to the panel2 (if possible). I just want to show the dynamic textareas in the panel2 .

Comment: Why don't you count the JTextAreas you are adding and check if you have reached a limit?

Comment: if your positioning is absolute(80,120) why can't you check for text area going out of panel? if textarea.size > 180 then its going out. If textArea.xposition + textArea.size > 180 then it goes out of panel..there are some more of such cases

Comment: @Costis Aivalis in flowlayout the textarea can be editable.means the textarea can be of any size... so i think count wont work for me...

Comment: @ tejas can you help me with an example for that

Comment: @tejas - that checking is the task of a ... LayoutManager: never-ever grab its job

Answer (score 1):

Set the layout *before* you add any elements to the panel. No not call `setBounds` as with layout manager present it likely has no effect at all.

I cannot explain how to layout your elements as from your question seems not possible to figure out that do you want to do. Best, post the drawing with elements as they should look like. `GridLayout` maybe would be good if you want to align multiple elements as in the table.

Comment: components using the grid layout will occupy the entire area . is it possible to control the component size according to user choice

Comment: i want to post an image regarding the question but it showing you require 10 reputations to post into it but i had 10 reputations . why i am not able to post